# Find a Noether normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $I \subseteq k[X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}]$ be the ideal generated by the maximal minors of the $2 \times 3$ matrix
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
> X_1 & X_2 & X_3\\
> X_2 & X_3 & X_4
> \end{pmatrix}.$$
>
> Find a Noether normalization $k[Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4] \subseteq k[X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4]$ such that $I \cap k[Y_1, Y_2, Y_3, Y_4] = (Y_1, \ldots, Y_r)$ for a suitable $r$.

**What I've done:** I never encountered what a maximal minor is, so after some searching I suppose it means the determinant(s) of the maximal submatrices, i.e. in this case all $2 \times 2$ submatrices which then are (by deleting a column): $\begin{pmatrix}
X_1 & X_2\\
X_2 & X_3
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
X_1 & X_3\\
X_2 & X_4
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
X_2 & X_3\\
X_3 & X_4
\end{pmatrix}.$ Then, taking determinants we get $I = (X_1 X_3 - X_{2}^{2}, X_1 X_4 - X_3 X_2, X_2 X_4 - X_{3}^{2})$. **Is this correct?**

The next step would be to use the constructive proof of [Noether's Normalization Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether_normalization_lemma). However, I can't seem to understand the entire procedure of that proof and how to apply it to this problem. Perhaps if someone can illustrate this process, then I will better understand it after seeing it done.

Comment: Your work so far is correct. If you're having trouble with the only-one-ideal aspect, perhaps you could pad this with an extra ideal?

Comment: I have no idea where to start to be honest. I also can't seem to find a concrete example of Noether normalization to at least practice this process on some example(s). Would it require a long answer to write the answer to it down?

Comment: Let me be perhaps a bit more concrete of why I can't seem to make any progress: The statement of the lemma says that we need a finitely generated algebra $A$ over a field $k$. So what is my finitely generated algebra $A$ in this problem? Once I have that, I need to know the generators of the algebra $A$. Then, the proof inducts on the generators. Then, I suppose I just use the inductive proof of the lemma to "construct" the algebraically independent elements?

Comment: So I am uncertain if I just don't get the entire process here but: are we taking as our finitely generated algebra $k [X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4]$ with generators $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4$ and then our result of $Y_i$ should be linear combinations of the $X_i$? I think perhaps if someone could write the answer to this would be much beneficial as this process seems very algorithmtic and best understood by seeing it done (and I'm certain once I see it, I will feel quite silly) ...

Comment: Would an answer given as Macaulay 2 code suite you? Prompted by your question, I just wrote a little recursive routine noethnorml, that takes as input a polynomial ring $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ and an ideal $I \subseteq R$ and returns a ring map $\theta:T_2=k[w_1,\ldots,w_m] \to R$ with $J=\theta^{-1}(I) = (w_p,\ldots, w_m)$ (with $p> m$ possible) such that $R/I$ is integral over $T_2/J$. You can try Macaulay2 online at https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/#home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $\mathrm{noethnorml}$ receives

1. A polynomial ring $R = A[x_1,\ldots,x_m]$ over a coefficient field $A$.
2. An ideal $I \subseteq R$ given by its generators.

It returns:

A map of polynomial rings

$$\theta: T_2 = A[w_1,\ldots,w_m] \to R$$

such that

1. $\theta^{-1}(I) = J = (w_p,\ldots,w_m) \subseteq T_2$ is an ideal of $T_2$. It can be zero (then $p > m$).
2. $R/I$ is an integral ring extension of $T_2/J$.

$\mathrm{noethnorml}$ does

A. If $I=0$ then return $\theta = \mathrm{id}_R:R \to R$.

Otherwise do

Select $f \in I$. We want to put $f$ in Noether-Position, that is make a coordinate change, such that $f$ in the new coordinates $y_i$ is of the form

$$(*) y_m^N + a_1 y_m^{N-1} + \cdots + a_m$$

where the $a_i$ are polynomials in $y_1,\ldots,y_{m-1}$.

So define $S=A[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$ and maps

$$\phi: S \to R, \quad y_i \mapsto x_i + \alpha_i x_m \text{ for } i < m \text{ and } y_m \to x_m$$

$$\psi: R \to S \quad x_i \mapsto y_i - \alpha_i y_m \text{ for } i < m \text{ and } x_m \to y_m$$

which are obviously inverse to each other.

The $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{m-1} \in \mathbb{Z}$ are random integers.

Now for generic $\alpha_i$ the polynomial

$$f_1 = \psi(f)$$

is of the above form $(*)$.

B. Now compute $I_1 = \phi^{-1}(I) \subseteq S$.

C. Define a ring $T=A[u_1,\ldots,u_{m-1}]$ and a map

$$\gamma:T \to S, \quad u_i \mapsto y_i$$

C1. Set $I_2 = \gamma^{-1}(I_1) \subseteq T$.

D. This is the recursion:

Call $\mathrm{noethnorml}$ with arguments $(T, I_2)$.
The result is

$$\theta: T_1 = A[v_1,\ldots,v_{m-1}] \to T$$

E. Call $\rho = \phi \circ \gamma \circ \theta:T_1 \to R$

F. Introduce a ring $T_2 = A[w_1,\ldots,w_m]$ and a ring map

$$\theta':T_2 \to R \quad \text{ with } w_i \mapsto \rho(v_i) \text{ for } i < m \text{ and } w_m \mapsto f$$

G. Return $\theta'$ as the result.